# Python sees LD_LIBRARY_PATH only when executing as root (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: python, security, environment-variables, apparmor, selinux

I am facing a tricky problem with LD_LIBRARY_PATH in python3.8 on Ubuntu 20.04.1.

When I execute **with my user** the following lines:

```
user@host>export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib
user@host>echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib
user@host>python -c 'import os;print(os.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"))'
None
```

Python is not able to access LD_LIBRARY_PATH (please note that other variables are accessible as usual).

When I execute **with root** the same:

```
root@host>export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib
root@host>echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib
root@host>python -c 'import os;print(os.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"))'
/usr/lib
```

it works flawlessly. I therefore suspect it is a safety configuration, I already tried:

1. AppArmor (from this [thread on opensuse forum](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/537634-Python-ignores-LD_LIBRARY_PATH-in-openSUSE)) : on my system there is no profile for python defined (`aa-status does` not show python, even when `ps aux | grep python` yields various running instances). There is however an abstraction defined in `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/python` which is included in `lsb_release` and `usr.bin.firefox` profiles. But neither of them should compromise the Python execution. The usual guides of creating a symlink in `/etc/apparmor.d/disable` do not work since there is no profile for python which I could disable.
2. SELINUX (see the comment [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643831/ld-library-path-cannot-be-seen-in-python-os-environ)): on my system there does neither `/etc/selinux/config` nor `sestatus` exist. So I assume it is disabled, although the folder and some packages are installed. To be sure I executed `setfacl -b /usr/bin/python3.8` (see this [thread on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/191903/how-do-i-remove-any-selinux-context-or-acl)) without any change.

Any sort of hint e.g. to other security flags / settings / out-of-the-box solutions (which do not include reinstalling the system from scratch) would be highly appreciated, since **I spent already 1 entire day on this**.

**Some optional Background**

I need to compile a rosnode running a python script, which includes C++ code with pybind11, which on the C++ side dynamically loads libraries available in the folders specified in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. When manually executing the lines shared above with a conda interpreter `~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python` it correctly sees the library path, so it seems to be bounded to the executable in `/usr/bin`. However I am unable to change the the python executable, since pybind11 uses old cmake find_package directives, always falling back to interpreters in `/usr/bin`. Workarounds such as using rpath variables or manually changing the path at runtime [see this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856116/changing-ld-library-path-at-runtime-for-ctypes) are not an option.

The same exact projects works on two other machines running a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 and a Debian Testing system. My recently updated ubuntu (from 18.04) therefore needs to have some hidden configuration issue, which I really would like to figure out.